# Копирование символов из строки(C)

Tags: c, строки

Написал функцию, в которой сначала вводится время в часах, минутах и секундах через ":" в строку str(например 02:16:10). Затем символы обозначающие каждый отдельный показатель времени копируются в соответствующую строку(h, min и sec). Затем каждая строка, в которую были скопированы символы выводится на экран. Но код не работает, строки h, min и sec не выводятся. Подскажите, в чём ошибка.

```
 void input()
{
    char str[8];
    gets(str);
    puts(str);
    int i = 0;
    char h[2], min[2], sec[2];
    while (str[i] != ':')
    {
        strncpy(h, str[i],1);
        i++;
    }
    i++;
    puts(h);
    while (str[i] != ':')
    {
        strncpy(min, str[i],1);
        i++;
    }
    i++;
    puts(min);
    while (str[i] != '/0')
    {
        strncpy(sec, str[i],1);
        i++;
    }
    puts(sec);
}
```

Comment: `char h[3], min[3], sec[3];..h[2]=min[2]=sec[2]='\00';`

Comment: .. `!= '/0'` => `!= '\00'`

Comment: Мне нужно. чтобы чч:мм:сс вводилось одной строкой

Comment: `strncpy(h, str[i],1);` => `strncpy(h,  &  str[i],1);`

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) позволяет решать подобные задачи более кратко:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char str[9] = "20:16:10";
  char h[3] = "hh", min[3] = "mm", sec[3] = "ss";
  int rc;
  
  if ((rc = sscanf(str, "%2s:%2s:%2s", h, min, sec)) == 3)
    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t", h, min, sec);
  else
    printf("'%s = %s:%s:%s' -- format error in (or just before) field  %d\n",
       str, h, min, sec, rc);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Comment: А что `strptime()` уже отменили? @АндрейГорбунов, вам на заметку.

Answer (score 0):

Строка в конце должна завершаться символом `'\00'`  *(не `'/0'`)* и строки должны иметь размеры, включающие этот символ.
Циклы копирования копируют всю строку в одно место *одну букву*. Надо смещать целевое место на одну букву и используя функцию `strncpy` передавать аргументом не одну букву, а адрес строки.
Со всеми исправлениями и проверкой вроде пашет :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void input(){
    char str[9]="12:34:56";
    //fgets(str,9,stdin);
    puts(str);
    int i = 0;
    char h[3], min[3], sec[3];
    int j=0;
    while (j<2 && str[i] != ':')
    {
        strncpy(h+ j ,& str[i],1);
        // или
        // h[j]=str[i];
        i++;
        ++j;
    }
    i++;
    h[2]='\00';
    puts(h);
    j=0;
    while (j<2 && str[i] != ':')
    {
        strncpy(min+ j , & str[i],1);
        // или
        // min[j]=str[i];
        i++;
        ++j;
    }
    i++;
    min[2]='\00';
    puts(min);
    j=0;
    while (j<2 && str[i] != '\00')
    {
        strncpy(sec+ j , & str[i],1);
        // или
        // sec[j]=str[i];
        i++;
        ++j;
    }
    sec[2]='\00';
    puts(sec);
}

int main(){
  input();
}
```

Comment: У меня почему-то выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Зачем? Всё делается с помощью стандартной `strptime()`.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось через strtok.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void input();


int main()
{
    input();
    return 0;
}

void input()
{
    char str[9] = "20:16:10", *context = NULL;
    char* str2 = strtok_s(str, ":",&context);
    printf("%s\n", str2);
    char h[3] = "\0", min[3]="\0", sec[3]="\0";
    while (str2)
    {
        printf("%s\n", str2);
        strcpy_s(h, 3, str2);
        str2 = strtok_s(NULL, ":", &context);
        printf("%s\n", str2);
        strcpy_s(min, 3, str2);
        str2 = strtok_s(NULL, ":", &context);
        printf("%s\n", str2);
        strcpy_s(sec, 3, str2);
        str2 = strtok_s(NULL, ":", &context);
    }
    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t", h, min, sec);
}
```